# remove linebreaks created by div with map-information

Tags: css, html, dictionary, line-breaks

I got a little problem with a map I'm creating.
I got a map wich i add pins to with css-coordinates.
The problem is that for each div I create it adds another linebreak or two beneath the map.
Since I got roughly 130 pins to add, i figured it might become a problem later on. 
Here is my code:

```
        <img src="bilder/kart.png" alt="kart" class="kartet">//Map


        <div class="naal london" onclick="writeText(london);" style="cursor:pointer;" title="London - Storbritannia"></div> //Pin #1
        <div class="naal dublin" onclick="writeText(dublin);" style="cursor:pointer;" title="Dublin - Irland"></div> //pin 2... and so on.
```

Is there a way to remove the spacing added by these div-tags, I were playing around with display:none and CSS-div-props / maxheight !important.... but nothing seems to do what I want without removing my pins.

In advance, thanks a bunch :)

Comment: They are within a table-cell, trid to configurate those props. aswell, but, yet again, no ressult

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, it was just as simple as adding another div and set the height-property of this to zero:

```
 <img src="bilder/kart.png" alt="kart" class="kartet">//Map
 <div id="sneaky">

        <div class="naal london" onclick="writeText(london);" style="cursor:pointer;" title="London - Storbritannia"></div> //Pin #1
        <div class="naal dublin" onclick="writeText(dublin);" style="cursor:pointer;" title="Dublin - Irland"></div> //pin 2... and so on.
</div>
```

And css it:

```
#sneaky     {
            height:0px;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey friend I am also trying to develop a map as you, I first ask you what you want to develop for android platform if it is easier, install a android SDK on your machine, and low google maps that will help you and greatly facilitate a good development, then it's only you begin to develop your pins on the maps points eg here is by bus, taxi points here is, here is a hospital or a school, here is highway think your thinking is this, then looking to download any maps that already half done and you will just have to do the job demarcations desired

Comment: Hi there :)! I create my own maps and pins, thank you for the suggestion tho, perhaps looking into some of those codes will reveal a solution to my problem :)